# Microsoft access date appearance

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table that looks like this
Date/sku/qty

I want to return all records where the Sku has a record for 25/06/2017 but not in 26/06/2017 and vice versa any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I don't know where to start

Comment: I want to be able to report new lines and expired lines based a a table as above

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I see you corrected the date examples. Still, date is a reserved word and should not use reserved words as names. The dates shown are in international format. Review: http://allenbrowne.com/ser-36.html.

Consider:

`SELECT [Date], SKU
FROM tablename
WHERE [Date]=#6/25/2017# AND NOT SKU IN (SELECT SKU FROM tablename WHERE [Date] =#6/26/2017#);`

Comment: Apologies the date is date/time format . What I need is to return all Sku with the date 26/06/2017 that do not have a matching record for 27/06/2017